# =Vlookup is not working for numbers with an Underline/Underscore in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
    1102      OK
    1102_1    OK
    1102_2    OK
    1103      OK
    1104      NOK
    1105      OK
```

I have a worksheet where I choose from a Dropdown menu("Data/Validation"list) my numbers like 1102 and then my `=Vlookup` looks in the other sheet an displays OK or NOK.
BUT when I have an underline in it like in 1102_1 die VLOOKUP stops working. How can I repair that?  All numbers are formatted in  Standard....

How can I avoid this fault?

Is it only possible if I remove the Underline?

Comment: You should probably use `=INDEX(array to return from, MATCH(lookup value, array to search in, FALSE))` As with @undeadherbs answer, this makes Excel do an exact match (specifically FALSE or 0 as the third argument to `MATCH`), rather than using its incredibly non-deterministic fuzzy matching 'feature'.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth argument to `VLOOKUP` is `range_lookup`.
`VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

From the docs: 
`If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.`

Apparently this approximate functionality does not understand the underscore character.

 
The solution is asking for an `exact match` by putting a comma at the end of the argument list. 
`=Vlookup(from_Cell,data_range,2,)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to ignore the underscored numbers completely? If so, you can do this:

LEFT( , 4)

Comment: do you have an idea why this don'T works with underlines in the text?